# Add a pressed state to any view same as the launcher icons

Tags: android, android-view

I would like to add a pressed state to most of my views, so that the view will be darken regardless of its background color/drawable **without creating xml selector to each view**.

Like in the launcher icons.

Like in the following picture the google analytics icon is darken when I press it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `ColorFilter`. Here's an example of one:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
private static final ColorFilter sDarkenFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mImageView.setColorFilter(sDarkenFilter);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mImageView.clearColorFilter();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can I add it to any view? textview/buttons as well?

Comment: `setColorFilter()` is just on `ImageView`, `Drawable`, and `Paint` classes, to my knowledge. You can just use a color selector for the text color, and for a button, you can call `button.getBackground().setColorFilter()`.

Comment: I have a grid adapter with dynamic data, which I am trying to set the color filter to every item, is there anyway of achieving that?
`convertView.setColorFilter(sDarkenFilter);`

Comment: Just set a touch listener for the item in `getView()`.

Comment: The returned view must be declared final, well thats a different question I suppose.

I am accepting your answer, thank you.